# repositioning panes in Spyder panes

Tags: python, spyder

New to Python and Spyder. How do I reposition the panes in Spyder.  I had them set with the editor in the upper left, the object inspector in the upper right, and the ipython console in the lower left. Somehow I messed it up, and can't figure out how to reposition them.  Have crawled all over the web, but no joy.

Thanks

jpl

Answer (score 46):

In the Spyder 4.0+ version, go to [View menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfLhU.png), unselect "lock panes and toolbars" then you can drag the top area of each pane and move them freely.

Answer (score 11):

Other answers are correct that you can recover past arrangements of the panes via the View/Window layouts menu, but if you want to actually create a new layout, that's another matter.

The fact is, it's pretty easy, once you know how. To move Help to the same pane that File explorer is in (in the picture below), the steps are:

1. Find Help in the same pane that Variable explorer is in, and click its tab to bring it to the front
2. Click the multiple windows icon in the upper right corner of the Help pane (see where the red arrows point?)
3. Help will detach from the rest of the window and you can now click & drag it to whatever pane - whether already existing or new - that you want to put it in

[image: How to rearrange panes in Spyder]

Comment: Unfortunately those multiple windows icons are gone in Spyder 4.1.1. I only have the little crosses (after unlocking the panes).

Answer (score 8):

For Spyder IDE just go to View -> Reset window layout

Answer (score 2):

just go to view->click on spyder default layout

that should work

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to select what panes you want to view under the "View" tab.

To stack panes simply drag and drop over each other. More details on http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~fangohr/blog/spyder-the-python-ide.html

Section 6 Multiple windows.

Answer (score 1):

On windows click on the 3 bars at the upright corner of the pane, undock and move the pane where you want. On Linux unselect View > lock panes and toolbars and move your pane.